# Prove Lp is not a metric for 0 < p < 1

Tags: real-analysis

I think that $\mathbb{L}_p$ fails the triangle inequality $\rho(x,z) \le \rho(x,y) + \rho(y,z)$. How do I prove it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try proving that for $0<x,y$ and $0<p<1$ the following inequality holds
$$x^p+y^p > (x+y)^p.$$
Thus the usual $p-$ norm will not be a metric.

One way of proving the above inequality is to consider the function $f(t)=1+t^p-(1+t)^p$ and determine its monotonic behavior.